# MyBatis Update two different Oracle SQL table at once

Tags: sql, spring, oracle, mybatis

I'm working on Spring Web Project and I want to update two columns from two different tables at once.

```
    <update id="updatePartnerWarned" parameterType="map">
    UPDATE
           M_PARTNER
       SET
           WARNED = WARNED + 1
     WHERE
           ID = #{id}
           
           
    UPDATE
           REPORT
       SET
           ISCHECKED = 'T'
         , ISWARNED = 'T'
     WHERE
           ID = #{id}
    </update>
```

This is what I expected to be working but it didn't.

Comment: Run each update with its own mapper. Make sure the method is annotated with `@Transactional`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe in Oracle (Unlike most other DBs) you can't do multiple queries like that so you would have to use a procedure for this:

```
<update id="updatePartnerWarned" parameterType="map">
    {call
        declare
        begin
            UPDATE M_PARTNER SET WARNED = WARNED + 1 WHERE ID = #{id}
            UPDATE REPORT SET ISCHECKED = 'T', ISWARNED = 'T' WHERE ID = #{id}
        end
    }
</update>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it into a pl/sql anonymous block:

```
begin
    UPDATE
           M_PARTNER
       SET
           WARNED = WARNED + 1
     WHERE
           ID = #{id};
           
           
    UPDATE
           REPORT
       SET
           ISCHECKED = 'T'
         , ISWARNED = 'T'
     WHERE
           ID = #{id};
end;
```